# Java HttpServletRequest get URL in browsers URL bar

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets

So I'm trying to grab the current URL of the page using Java's request object. I've been using request.getRequestURI() to preform this, but I noticed that when a java class reroutes me to a different page off a servlet request getRequestURI gives that that address as opposed to the orginal URL that was typed in the browser and which still shows in the browser.

Ex: \AdvancedSearch:
`getRequestURI()` returns "\subdir\search\search.jsp"

I'm looking for a way to grab what the browser sees as the URL and not what that page knows is only a servlet wrapper.

Comment: The answer in the link below will definitely help someone.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024344/user-login-with-jsf-2-0/39379256#39379256](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024344/user-login-with-jsf-2-0/39379256#39379256)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If your current request is coming from an "inside the app-server" forward or include, the app-server is expected to preserve request information as request attributes. The specific attributes, and what they contain, depends on whether you're doing a forward or an include.

For `<jsp:include>`, the original parent URL will be returned by `request.getRequestURL()`, and information about the included page will be found in the following request attributes:

```
     javax.servlet.include.request_uri
     javax.servlet.include.context_path
     javax.servlet.include.servlet_path
     javax.servlet.include.path_info
     javax.servlet.include.query_string
```

For `<jsp:forward>`, the new URL will be returned by `request.getRequestURL()`, and the original request's information will be found in the following request attributes:

```
     javax.servlet.forward.request_uri
     javax.servlet.forward.context_path
     javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path
     javax.servlet.forward.path_info
     javax.servlet.forward.query_string
```

These are set out in section 8.3 and 8.4 of the Servlet 2.4 specification.

However, be aware that this information is only preserved for internally-dispatched requests. If you have a front-end web-server, or dispatch outside of the current container, these values will be null. In other words, you may have no way to find the original request URL.

Comment: I tried out.println(request.getAttribute("request_uri"));
 out.println(request.getAttribute("context_path"));
 out.println(request.getAttribute("servlet_path"));
 out.println(request.getAttribute("path_info"));
 out.println(request.getAttribute("query_string"));
All returned null. Does this mean I'm screwed?

Comment: The actual attribute name is "javax.servlet.include.request_uri", not "request_uri"

Comment: Thanks that works. Need to add a little more logic in my navigation, but hey saves me a lot of trouble. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Just did a slight tidy of the solution by Ballsacian1

```
String currentURL = null;
if( request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri") != null ){
    currentURL = (String)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
}
if( currentURL != null && request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.include.query_string") != null ){
    currentURL += "?" + request.getQueryString();
}
```

The null checks are going to run a lot more efficiently than String comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for this. While not currently of much use to me, This is one of those questions that I'm sure will come back to me in the future.

Comment: @readikus - should that be `javax.servlet.forward.query_string` instead of `javax.servlet.include.query_string`?

Answer (score 5):

```
String activePage = "";
    // using getAttribute allows us to get the orginal url out of the page when a forward has taken place.
    String queryString = "?"+request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.query_string");
    String requestURI = ""+request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    if(requestURI == "null") {
        // using getAttribute allows us to get the orginal url out of the page when a include has taken place.
        queryString = "?"+request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.include.query_string");
        requestURI = ""+request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.include.request_uri");
    }
    if(requestURI == "null") {
        queryString = "?"+request.getQueryString();
        requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    }
    if(queryString.equals("?null")) queryString = "";
    activePage = requestURI+queryString;
```

Answer (score 4):

${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}
 -- if you access it form jsp, using Expression Language

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
<%=request.getRequestURL().toString()%>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the HTTP requested path without know the state of the internal flow of the request, use this method:

```
public String getUri(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String r = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    return r == null ? request.getRequestURI() : r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as @kdgregory, but you can rather use the Request Dispatcher constants.

```
javax.servlet.include.request_uri        RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI
javax.servlet.include.context_path       RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_CONTEXT_PATH
javax.servlet.include.servlet_path       RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_SERVLET_PATH
javax.servlet.include.path_info          RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_PATH_INFO
javax.servlet.include.query_string       RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_QUERY_STRING
```