# How to get url path from jsp in Spring MVC framework

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

To remove the language toggle from the page view(Comfirmation Page)

I found this code but it doesn't work in Spring MVC

```
<c:if test="${!fn:contains(pageContext.request.servletPath,'/comfirmation')}">
         //Other Code
</c:if>
```

- My actual url is (**ShoppingCart.jsp**).
- It is used when **/viewCart.htm,/updateCart.htm,/Confirmation.htm**,etc.
- So, the user go to the **/Confirmation.htm**, it also redirect to the ShoppingCart.jsp but the url path in the browser is /Confirmation.htm.
- I want to remove the language toggle when call the /Confirmation.htm in the above mention.

Comment: Check out this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256562/java-httpservletrequest-get-url-in-browsers-url-bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I got it. Here we go

```
<%
    String url=request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path").toString();
    if(url.equals("/Confirmation.htm")){    
%>
     //Language Toggle code
<% } %>
```

I decided to use this. Another way is that storing url path in session since front controller.

Comment: (Not sure, but) probably `<c:if test="${!fn:contains(requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path'],'/confirmation')}">` also should work.

Comment: <c:if test="${!fn:contains(requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path'],'/confir‌​mation')}"> worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

the `pageContext.request.servletPath` will give you the path of the jsp (and not the url your browser shows).

The request is forwarded to a controller, which returns a path to a view. The view ist called using a second internal request