# Spring MVC Request Life Cycle

Tags: http, servlets, spring-mvc

This seems like a pretty basic question but I unfortunately don't know the answer and can't seem to find it.

I'm trying to understand the lifecycle of an initial POST/GET to a Java 6 server running Spring 2.5 on Tomcat 6.

I noticed that for an HttpServletRequest, request.getRequestURL() **in a controller** returns the original request to which it is mapped (ex. "http://localhost:8080/computers/accessories.html").  That same invocation in the corresponding JSP returns the path to the JSP itself (ex. "http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/jsp/category.jsp").  I was expecting to see the original HTML request!

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is specified in the [api doc](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29):

> If this request has been forwarded using
>   RequestDispatcher.forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,
>   javax.servlet.ServletResponse), the server path in the reconstructed
>   URL must reflect the path used to obtain the RequestDispatcher, and
>   not the server path specified by the client.

Look at `getRequestURI`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Came across a thread which also addresses this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256562/java-httpservletrequest-get-url-in-browsers-url-bar