# how to get the url of the initially requested page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I use the following web.xml setting to direct unlogged-in user to /faces/loginPage.xhtml.
In /faces/loginPage.xhtml I will authenticate the user and redirect the user to the home page.

Now I want to redirect the user to the page she initially requested, instead of the home page.  How do I do that? Specifically, how to get the url of the initially requested page?

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>MyConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>wrcoll</web-resource-name>
        <description />
        <url-pattern>/faces/secured/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description />
        <role-name>myUser</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>my_ldap_domain</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/loginPage.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Comment: A detailed answer is here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024344/user-login-with-jsf-2-0/39379256#39379256](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024344/user-login-with-jsf-2-0/39379256#39379256)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be performing the login through a JSF managed bean instead of through `j_security_check`. Because if you were using the latter, this is already automatically taken into account.

The FORM based authentication login page is been displayed by a [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) the usual Servlet API way. So the request URI of the initially requested page is available as a request attribute with the name as specified by [`RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI), which has a value of [`"javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI).

So, in EL context it's available as

```
#{requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}
```

And in JSF context it's available as

```
String originalURL = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
```

This needs to be collected on the initial request, not on the form submit. Easiest would be to grab it in the constructor of a `@ViewScoped` managed bean which is attached to the page. An alternative with a `@RequestScoped` bean is to enclose a plain HTML `<input type="hidden">` in with that value in the login form and set it as `@ManagedProperty`.