# Get current URL in Webapplication

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am in process to capture Current URL as its being displayed in the browser's address bar in my JSP page and have few options to get it done.

- Using `javax.servlet.include.request_uri` and other defined in Servlet 2.4 specification.I refer this thread to get details about it [java-httpservletrequest-get-url-in-browsers-url-bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256562/java-httpservletrequest-get-url-in-browsers-url-bar).

In my current application, we are going to put web-server in front of our application server as than it seems that those values will be of not any use.

I have another way to take help of javascript's  `document.URL` but i am not sure how reliable it is going to be.

I need to get the details about the location of the user and if I can use `getRequestURI()`, it will return me something like `www.abc.com/abc/search.jsp`.

In short, all I want to capture the URL being there in the address bar of the browser and save it in a hidden field of my JSP page.

I am not sure what is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: You want "about the location of the user" and getRequestURI(). Question is not very clear. Can u make it simple what do you want.

Comment: all i want to capture the URL being there in the address bar of the browser and save it in a hidden field of my JSP page

Comment: Write the getRequestURI() in the jsp. That should do right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a javascript solution, you can use **window.document.location** object and its properties:

```
console.log(window.document.location.protocol);
http:
console.log(window.document.location.host);
stackoverflow.com
console.log(window.document.location.port);

console.log(window.document.location.href);
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845606/get-current-url-in-webapplication
console.log(window.document.location.pathname);
/questions/10845606/get-current-url-in-webapplication
```

You can understand other parameters reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) at MDN.

Comment: Thanks for the input and i am settling down to javascript based solution.i have a question will `window.document.location.pathname` will pick the query string if any append to the URL?

Comment: Nope, that is the location.search bit. Check out the link I'm adding to my answer.

Answer (score 10):

In Java, you can do this:

```
 public static String getCurrentUrl(HttpServletRequest request){

    URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString())

    String host  = url.getHost();
    String userInfo = url.getUserInfo();
    String scheme = url.getProtocol();
    String port = url.getPort();
    String path = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    String query = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.query_string");
    URI uri = new URI(scheme,userInfo,host,port,path,query,null)
    return uri.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a hidden field in your form

```
<input type="hidden" id="myurl" name="myurl"/>
```

then write a javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('myurl').value = window.location.href
</script>
```

is that help?