# Put parameters into url of webservlet

Tags: servlets

I'm using a Webservlet and I would like to pass parameters in the url itself. Something like

```
@WebServlet("/profile/{id}")
public class ProfileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        String idstr = req.getParameter("id");
        int id = idstr == null ? (int)req.getSession().getAttribute("userid") : Integer.parseInt(idstr);
        Profile profile = ProfileDAO.getForId(id);
        req.setAttribute("profile",profile);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/profile.jsp").forward(req,res);
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that allows me to do this. I know I could do `/profile?idstr=1234` or something, but is there a way I can slap it into the URL with WebServlet? Or do I need a different framework to do this...

Comment: It will be much easier to just use any RESTful webservice implementation: spring-ws / apache-cxf.. Otherwise as far as I know you need to parse the values out of the URL on your own and dispatch the correct function based on parsing results

Answer (score 0):

I was looking myself for this long enough, and found the solution. 
You can try getting the url, that is currently put into browser url, for example:

> ../profile/this_id

You can't get this

> this_id

in a simple way, but because of internal servlet forward dispatching, which is not always bound to. Sometimes  `request.getRequestURI()` works as needed, you can check it:

```
String url = null;
url = (String) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
url = url == null ? ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI() : url;
```

or

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.include.request_uri")
```

in case you use  `<jsp:include tag>` 
If you URL is

> www.example.com/profile/Ted

the result will be

> profile/Ted

so you can simply get what you need.
For more info look here [Java HttpServletRequest get URL in browsers URL bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256562/java-httpservletrequest-get-url-in-browsers-url-bar)