# How to know if a JSP file is beeing included by another one?

Tags: java, jsp

I have `x.jsp` that can either be served as the whole response, or being included in several other jsp files.

So how can I know inside `x.jsp` if it is being included by another file or not?

Comment: Why do you want to know that? What will you do with the knowledge?

Comment: you can try accessing values from included jsp from the includer.

Comment: I already thought to some workaround (for example using jsp:param), but it is not the most elegant way, since I would need to modify all the files that include the jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of the attribute `javax.servlet.include.request_uri` in your `x.jsp` page. If set, the jsp page was included.

Further details here: 
[Java HttpServletRequest get URL in browsers URL bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256562/java-httpservletrequest-get-url-in-browsers-url-bar)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hidden field in the 'other files' and if you are including `x.jsp` you should set a value for it, and within `x.jsp` when you wanna know if its including you should check if that hidden fields `value == 'value'`.

Comment: How does a JSP check the value of a any `input` field?

Answer (score 0):

If `x.jps` have knowledge about inclusion, it means that some best practices is ignored:

- MVC pattern is thrown away because your `x.jsp` is not just a **view**, but also some kind of **controller**.
- Possibly the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is broken. Try split `x.jsp` to `y.jsp` and `z.jsp`, or introduce a variable which will contain value for appropriate case
- It possibly increases [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29) because `x.jsp` needs additional data about enviroment.

Of course these practices are not mandatory but you need a strong reason why you ignore them.

Please give us more information about your case or rephrase you question

**Edit**

My answer is abstract as your question is abstract. Get us your jsp, what should be changed and I hope you get better answer.

Comment: Basically, it's better if the caller gives the thing it is calling all the information needed instead of having it reach back to the caller later. This is true in writing pure Java code too. You can use a program like grepwin to do a search and replace in all the JSP files.

Comment: Architecture (and bad habits) made us go away from "pure" MVC. (Pls don't tell me to refactor, it would cost hundreds of men days). Jsp files are not classes, and about coupling and so on take a look at useBean tag or session/request variables. Each Jsp file is more like a procedure call than an object. Thanks for your answer but it is not helpful for me.