# Obtain specific part of URL

Tags: java, html, jsp, url, redirect

I have the following `jsp` where I need to modify a specific part of my current `url`

```
String path = request.getRequestURL().toString();
...
response.sendRedirect("https://new.user.SAME.SAME/main.jsp");
```

I would like to take the `XXX` part of my current `url` and put it in the `sendRedirect` link.

For an example, if I am currently on
https://old.user.domain.com/main.jsp, then the new link should be https://new.user.domain.com/main.jsp.

The only thing constantly changes is the user part. I currently use `response.sendRedirect("/main.jsp")` to redirect on the same site, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get the part between the dots.

**Solved**

```
String user = path.substring(path.indexOf("old.") + 4, path.indexOf(".domain"));
response.sendRedirect("https://new." + user + ".domain.com/main.jsp");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java HttpServletRequest get URL in browsers URL bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256562/java-httpservletrequest-get-url-in-browsers-url-bar)

Comment: What was suggested there returns all `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Request URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI()) is a part of URL you're looking for:

```
request.getRequestURI()
```

Comment: That one actually returns anything after `.com` and I don't really need that part. I need to modify the `user` part.

Comment: Oh, sorry, misunderstood your question. Then... you can take 'request.getServerName()', tokenize it by "." and replace first (or how many you need) token.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

String user = path.substring(path.indexOf("old.") + 4, path.indexOf(".domain"));
response.sendRedirect("https://new." + user + ".domain.com/main.jsp");