# Java HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL() don't deliver the calling url

Tags: java, servlets, url-rewriting, facescontext

I have a problem to get the calling `URL`,

For example, I call `"www.xyz.de/abc"`, the `urlrewite.xml` change it to `"www.xyz.de/test.jsp"` to call the correct `JSP`.

In the bean, I want to get the calling `URL` `"www.xyz.de/abc"`

Here's my code:

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) 
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String url = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
```

Can somebody help, how I get the calling `URL`?

Comment: What HTTP-server are we talking about here?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1256637/608424

Comment: is a Tomcat v7.0